# Why isn't brew symbolically linking lld into /usr/local/bin when it installs llvm?

Tags: homebrew

I have installed *llvm* with *brew install llvm* and it shows up as installed with *brew list*.

```
% brew list
... llvm ...
% brew --prefix
/usr/local
% brew --version
Homebrew 3.3.9
...
```

The *lld* binary (with various symbolic aliases) shows up in Cellar. For example, *ld.lld* is a symbolic link back to *lld*:

```
% ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_2/bin/ld.lld
lrwxr-xr-x  1 chris  admin  3 Sep 24 09:18 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_2/bin/ld.lld@ -> lld
```

When I run the *ld.lld* binary it says:

```
% /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_2/bin/ld.lld --version
Homebrew LLD 13.0.0 (compatible with GNU linkers)
```

However, *lld* or *ld.lld* isn't being linked into */usr/local/bin* or anywhere standard that I could find.

```
% ls /usr/local/bin/lld
ls: /usr/local/bin/lld: No such file or directory
% ls /usr/local/bin/ld.lld
ls: /usr/local/bin/ld.lld: No such file or directory
```

I don't want to put a long brittle link to *ld.lld* in a script. Any idea why it's not getting linked into a standard location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily find out an answer to your question with the command `brew info llvm`, which will show this:

> llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
> because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
> parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

> If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

> For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

Supposing you already use CMake, then to add linking info to your `CMakeLists.txt` file may be accomplished as described in following:

1 [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077414/how-to-set-the-ldflags-in-cmakelists-txt).

2 [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html).

3 [helpful introductory notes](https://elpauer.org/stuff/learning_cmake.pdf).